# Image href property rendered if image is contained within an anchor tag

Tags: 2013-sp1, multimedia

In a rich text field in Tridion, I have added the following code:

```
<a href="https://www.thisisatest.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Test Alt Text" src="tcm:5-222222" class="footer__logo"/></a>
```

tcm:5-222222 is the image multimedia component containing the uploaded image.

However, when published out this renders as:

```
<a href="https://www.thisisatest.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="Test Alt Text" href="/_images/testimage_tcm9-222222.png" src="/_images/testimage_tcm9-222222.png" class="footer__logo" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Test title"></a>
```

Why is the href attribute added to the img tag in the rendered version? This makes it invalid markup. Is this is a bug with the Tridion rendering? Is there a good workaround for this problem, other than to keep the image outside of the CMS?

For reference, this is the markup of the 'Summary' field in the schema template:

```
 <xsd:element name="summary" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tcmi:XHTML">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">5</tcm:Size>
              <tcm:FilterXSLT xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
                  <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
                  <template name="FormattingFeatures">
                    <FormattingFeatures xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.2/FormatArea" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                      <Doctype>Transitional</Doctype>
                      <AccessibilityLevel>2</AccessibilityLevel>
                      <DisallowedActions></DisallowedActions>
                      <DisallowedStyles></DisallowedStyles>
                    </FormattingFeatures>
                  </template>
                  <template match="/ | node() | @*">
                    <copy>
                      <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
                    </copy>
                  </template>
                  <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
                    <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
                  </template>
                  <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
                    <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
                    <text> </text>
                  </template>
                </stylesheet>
              </tcm:FilterXSLT>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
```

Comment: Did you use any custom RichText Resolver TBB anything? could you please edit your question and provide the TBBs used on that page and PT and CT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this. In my TBB I was replacing the xlink:href property of the output string with an href linking to the component URL.